# Getting a transition matrix to do a correlation in RStudio

Tags: matrix, transition, correlation

I am trying to isolate just the transition matrix so I can do a correlation of the data. I can't get it figured out how to. I can find the values of the transition matrix from "fit". I can't get any values. I need to run a correlation test of the transition matrix.  I also need to be able to plug in any data I need from a timeseries so I can't just use the numbers from fit and do the:

```
A = matrix( c(0.97487437, 0.02512563, 0.00000000, 0.000,
               0.04950495, 0.90099010, 0.04950495, 0.000,
               0.00000000, 0.05000000, 0.90000000, 0.050,
               0.00000000 ,0.00000000, 0.02500000 ,0.975
    ), # the data elements 
     nrow=4,              # number of rows 
     ncol=4,              # number of columns 
     byrow = TRUE)        # fill matrix by rows 
head(A) 

dat=data.frame(x=0:600, y=sin((0:600)/120*2*pi))
plot(dat)
str(dat)
dat$state=NA  #gives empty column of NA

#turn timeseries values into states 1,2,3,4
ymin=min(dat$y)
ymax=max(dat$y)
ystep=(ymax-ymin)/4
ymark=(1:3)*ystep+ymin

dat$state=(dat$y>ymark[3])+(dat$y>ymark[2])+(dat$y>ymark[1])+     
(dat$y>=ymin)  #gives the 4 states
head(dat)

 Pfit2=markovchainFit(data=dat2$state)$estimate
Pstderr2=markovchainFit(data=dat2$state)$standardError
Pfittm=markovchainFit(data=dat2$state)$transitionMatrix
dim(Pfit2)
[1] 4
> plot(Pfittm)
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
3: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
4: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```